# Как наложить текст на картинку? Для всех экранов

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть такая картинка. Каким образом мне текст вставлять в желтую рамку? так чтобы на всех экранах она была именно на той позиции.

А то я наложил поверх картинки текст и в dp сдвиг сделал до желтого квадртаа. Но так не пойжет, так как на разных экранах текст у меня то выше желтого квадрата, то ниже, то вообще сехала

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вычислите координаты картинки в пикселях.
2. В зависимости от них вычислите координаты для текста.
3. Поместите текст по вычисленным координатам.

Comment: Я так сделал только использовал DP. Так ведь все слезло. На одном макете hdpi нормально. А на xhdpi все слезло.

А в пикселях так еще хуже будет